# Mapping to a sub domain to localhost URL

Tags: dns, windows-server-2008, subdomain, redmine, bitnami

I'm unable to figure out how to point subdomain.domain.com to this kid of a url which is accessible from the localhost as, `http://localhost:5200/redmine/`.

I have installed this on a Windows 2008 R2 server, and want to access it using subdomain.domain.com

I know how to point subdomain to a server IP address, but not sure, how to bind this subdomain request to particular application URL?

Note that I have installed redmine using Bitnami stack.

Any hint/guide will be better as how to proceed with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really about DNS, but about how to have an application running on a custom port respond on port 80.

You have two options:

1. Make your redmine installation respond on port 80 and serve incoming requests directly.
2. Use a *reverse proxy* to forward incoming requests on port 80 to redmine running on port 5200.

Option 1 isn't doable if your web server already listens on port 80.

For option 2, the DNS entry for *subdomain.domain.com* should be configured with the server's public IP adress. On your web server, you should have an (empty) web site responding to the subdomain.

I never used [IIS as a reverse proxy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosag/archive/2010/04/02/setting-up-a-reverse-proxy-using-iis-url-rewrite-and-arr.aspx), but I'm sure this can be set up [relatively easily](http://sahelp.sharepointforall.com/FAQ/bconfigure_IIS.html). On IIS6 I'd recommend [IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com/) which can do reverse proxy.

Otherwise you may also use apache as a reverse proxy, and you may consider spinning up *multiple redmine instances* as well as serving *static content* directly from the webserver with *aggressive cache headers*. Here's an example apache configuration (from [here](https://raw.github.com/gist/1148622/090bbc0d63e90bc9a6027eb6b47c674c4aa5867a/httpd-proxa-mongrel.conf)):

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin admin@domain.local
    ServerName redmine.domain.local

    DocumentRoot "C:/redminepath/public"

    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    <Proxy balancer://redmine_cluster>
        BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:8081
        BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:8082
        BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:8083
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <DirectoryMatch "/(javascripts|images|stylesheets|plugin_assets|themes)">
        <FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpe?g|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
            ExpiresActive On
            ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
        </FilesMatch>
    </DirectoryMatch>
    <FilesMatch "favicon\.ico$">
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
    </FilesMatch>

    # Let apache serve the static content
    ProxyPass /images !
    ProxyPass /stylesheets !
    ProxyPass /javascripts !
    ProxyPass /favicon.ico !
    ProxyPass /plugin_assets !
    ProxyPass /themes !

    # Proxy all other requests
    ProxyPass / balancer://redmine_cluster/
    ProxyPassReverse / balancer://redmine_cluster/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Just a note that I have IIS as well and redmine is installed using Bitnami. I'm still not clear how to do it.

Comment: What exactly is not clear? Did you take a look at the links describing how to configure IIS as a reverse proxy?

Comment: Yes, I have gone through it, but didn't had an idea as whether I should do that using IIS or use Apache as a reverse proxy, or do I need to do both?

Comment: Since you have IIS, use IIS. This will be the _middle man_ between the requests coming in on your subdomain, and your application responding on a local port. First step is to add a web site to IIS which responds to the subdomain. Next step is to install the ARR module for IIS. Third you'll need to add rewrite rules - rules to rewrite inbound requests, and rules to modify outgoing content (in order to not have your internal redmine url in the output).

Comment: Okay, this make sense. But still not clear what should I follow, as I've installed it using Bitnami, they have the similar guide here http://wiki.bitnami.org/Applications/BitNami_Redmine_Stack I'm trying it now.. but not sure whether it will work or not... as port 80 is already occupied by the IIS. Pls advise.

Comment: I'm now trying with an ARR module for IIS, following this guide. http://jonalb.com/post/2010/10/23/TeamCity-On-Port-80-In-IIS.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - IIS is supposed to listen on port 80. Once your subdomain works on IIS (like a regular web site, hence port 80), you continue with step 2: Install ARR module. But it looks like Bitnami stack includes an apache server... Of course you won't be able to run 2 different web servers on the same port. If you want to make it work with apache, deactivate or uninstall IIS.