# Port configuration for Bitnami Redmine on domain on win 2008 server

Tags: apache, iis-7, windows-server-2008, redmine, bitnami

I've installed Redmine using Bitnami Stack on Win Server 2008 R2 64 bit. I already have IIS running over there, and wants to configure subdomain.domain.com to access the redmine which can be accessed on `http://127.0.0.1:3000/redmine`.

I'm following this guide (http://wiki.bitnami.org/Applications/BitNami_Redmine_Stack) to do the same. But unable to get it working.

After configuring I can't access Redmine altogether, but still access Bitnami page on the `http://127.0.0.1:3000/`

I want to confirm what port should I configure to listen in below, should I leave it port 80 or configure it to listen on port 3000? Pls advise.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin example.com
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias server
  ErrorLog "logs/error.log" 
  CustomLog "logs/access.log" combined
 # this not only blocks access to .svn directories, but makes it                
 # appear as though they aren't even there, not just that they are              
 # forbidden                                                                    
 <DirectoryMatch "^/.*/\.svn/">
    ErrorDocument 403 /404.html
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
  </DirectoryMatch>
  # This passes through remote_user to mongrel                                  
  RewriteEngine On
  # Redirect non-static requests to cluster                                     
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ balancer://redminecluster%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]
</VirtualHost>

#ProxyPass / balancer://redminecluster
#ProxyPassReverse / balancer://redminecluster

<Proxy balancer://redminecluster>
  BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3001
  BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:3002
</Proxy>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mapping to a sub domain to localhost URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768164/mapping-to-a-sub-domain-to-localhost-url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already have IIS running in port 80 and serving other applications what you could try is to configure IIS as a reverse proxy for apache.

https://serverfault.com/questions/47537/can-iis-be-configure-to-forward-request-to-another-web-server